# How to change the text style of a label in a Navigation Bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, label, bottom-navigation-bar

I'm doing a flutter app and I have two classes with a BottomNavigationBar. In one of them the text is bigger than in the other one and it has a different color too. How can I change the text style to have both of them with the same font size and color.

---

I have the following code for the first class:

```
items: [ BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.group, color: Colors.black87),
            label: 'Contactos',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.star_border),
            label: '',
          ),
        ],
```

and I added a themeData to change the default color:

```
theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
          primary: Colors.black87,
        ),
      ),
```

---

For the second class I have the following code:

```
items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.grey),
            label:'',
              ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.black87),
              label: 'Favoritos',
              ),
        ],
```

and I added a selectedLabelStyle to change the label color but it does nothing:

```
    selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
```

Result:
[first class label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVfKm.png)
[second class label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aeY8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectedItemColor` to modify the color of label.

there seems to be a bug or maybe its just how it was designed

[bug tracking](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67897)

Answer (score 0):

If you use

**selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),**

in **BottomNavigationBar**

You need to use

**unselectedLabelStyle**

**selectedLabelStyle**

**selectedItemColor**

**unselectedItemColor**

Hope this will help you.